# Google Maps GMSGroundOverlay delegate with Swift

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, delegates, swift, xcode6

I'm having an issue using objective-c delegates with swift. I want to overlay an image on google maps, then execute some other code if the overlay is touched. I was able to overlay the image and display maps, but I can't get the other code to execute for the tap event. Xcode 6 doesn't autocomplete objective-c delegates for swift, so I tried translating the original to get it to work according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189946/call-facebook-delegates-in-swift). Anyone know how to get these to work?

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        /* MapView inital values & dependencies */
        let initialLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.78, -122.41)
        let initialDirection = CLLocationDirection()
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(initialLocation, zoom: 10)

        /* Set up MapView */
        var mapView_ = GMSMapView(frame: CGRectZero)
        mapView_.camera = camera
        mapView_.myLocationEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView_
        mapView_.delegate = self


        let southwest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.72, -122.35)
        let northeast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.80,-122.52)

        let overlayBounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: southwest, coordinate: northeast)

        /* add opacity and overlay */
        var img = UIImage(named:"image.png")
        img = addOpacity(img, 0.5)
        var overlay = GMSGroundOverlay(bounds: overlayBounds, icon: img)


        overlay.tappable = true
        overlay.bearing = 0
        overlay.map = mapView_

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapOverlay:(GMSOverlay *)overlay;

    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, overlay: GMSOverlay){
        //other code here...
    }
```

Comment: Having the same issue now, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of an Objc->swift translation question. Well at least it is when you have the answer:

(note I did not actually create the answer I stole it from this very helpful little tool) http://objectivec2swift.net/#/converter

It reported (correctly, and something which was in Xcode's autocomplete as at 20 feb 2015)

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapOverlay overlay: GMSOverlay!) {

}
```