# How to change the text of Textfield on keyboard Done button in Swift?

Tags: swift3, uitextfield

Hello all i know its very simple question but i did not found on google as well.

In my case i am setting some default text in textfield and what i want is if user wants to give the different name to it then this new name should go the server otherwise the default text.

Basically i want is rename functionality should be done when user press keyboard's done button but i dont know how to do that please help.

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditingDidChange(sender: AnyObject) {
       println("textField: \(textField.text)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other textFields that the user will be completing or is this the only field?  If there are other fields to complete, just add a "submit" button with an action and tie your function to push all textFields to your server that way.

If you only have one field for the email address, you have another solution.

You've got an action here`@IBAction func textFieldEditingDidChange(sender: AnyObject) {` and what you most likely want to do is implement a delegate method on the text field. This way when the textField is changed your function will be called.  Just put your default text in the placeholder on the interface builder attributes inspector pane or add it to the view did load with code. `textfield.text = "default text"`. In any event the function won't trigger unless the user edits the textField.  You may want to add another way to pull this data if the user doesn't edit the field, you can tie the push to server function with a segue or by calling `viewWillDisappear().`

There are a few steps to switch to the delegate method.   [This link has a good example of what is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171857/implementing-uitextfielddelegate-with-swift/24604090#24604090).

First you need to add a UITextFieldDelegate to the class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

Then in your viewDidLoad() add a delegate to your textfield and set your default text.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    textfield.delegate = self
    textfield.text = "default text"
}
```

Now add your delegate method.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
     print("textField: \(textfield.text!)")
}
```

Most Importantly, change your action to an outlet and make sure to remove the send event in the connection inspector.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!
```

Comment: hi @Christopher i am having 2textfields and i want to change the text on keyboard done button is there any way to do this ?

Comment: You can do this in interface builder on the attributes inspector and go to Text Input Traits section and then choose from the "Return Key" dropdown.  You have a lot of choices to change it from Return to Done, Continue, Go, etc.

Comment: hey i already done this but the problem is when i type anything and press done button it wont change whichever default value i have set as text its returning me that value only.

Comment: Inside your `textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)` you need to pull the info from the textfield with textfield.text.