# Swift perform action when become first responder

Tags: swift

Is there a default method that is called when a UITextField or similar becomes the first responder, in order to have actions occur at that point?

Answer (score 1):

The apple documentation says this in its first step

> Before becoming the first responder, the text field calls its delegate’s textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:) method. Use that method to allow or prevent the editing of the text field’s contents.

UITextFieldDelegate:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate

UITextViewDelegate:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate

[How to implement UITextFieldDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171857/implementing-uitextfielddelegate-with-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the UItextfield delegate methods in this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate) 
and choose the one that fits your need.

Just don't forget to make assign the UItextfield.delegate to the class using it.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass your `UITextField` to handle first responder notifications. Just conform the view controller to the protocol and implement the two delegate methods. You'll be notified there.

```
protocol UITextFieldResponderDelegate: AnyObject {
    func becameFirstResponder()
    func resignedAsFirstResponder()
}

class UITextFieldCustom: UITextField {

    weak var responderDelegate: UITextFieldResponderDelegate?

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        responderDelegate?.becameFirstResponder()
        return super.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        responderDelegate?.resignedAsFirstResponder()
        return super.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}

class SomeViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldResponderDelegate {

    private let textField = UITextFieldCustom()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.responderDelegate = self
    }

    func becameFirstResponder() {
        print("became first responder")
    }

    func resignedAsFirstResponder() {
        print("resigned as first responder")
    }

}
```

If you had multiple text fields within the same view controller that you wanted to handle notifications on, simply switch on them in the delegate.